# WSL apt install jdk results in 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, ubuntu-22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

Windows 11 WSL. Installing JDK 11 results in the error: 404 not found.

```
 wsl> sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf ca-certificates-java fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core java-common libasound2 libasound2-data
      libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgraphite2-3 libharfbuzz0b
      libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libnspr4 libnss3 libpcsclite1 openjdk-11-jre-headless
    Suggested packages:
      default-jre libasound2-plugins alsa-utils cups-common liblcms2-utils pcscd openjdk-11-demo openjdk-11-source libnss-mdns
      fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf ca-certificates-java fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core java-common libasound2 libasound2-data
      libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgraphite2-3 libharfbuzz0b
      libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libnspr4 libnss3 libpcsclite1 openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jre-headless
    0 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 260 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 410 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
    Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 alsa-topology-conf all 1.2.5.1-2 [15.5 kB]
    Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasound2-data all 1.2.6.1-1ubuntu1 [19.1 kB]
    Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libasound2 amd64 1.2.6.1-1ubuntu1 [390 kB]
    Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 alsa-ucm-conf all 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.1
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
    Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 java-common all 0.72build2 [6782 B]
    Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libavahi-common-data amd64 0.8-5ubuntu5 [23.9 kB]
    Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libavahi-common3 amd64 0.8-5ubuntu5 [23.7 kB]
    Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libavahi-client3 amd64 0.8-5ubuntu5 [28.1 kB]
    Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1
    Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 liblcms2-2 amd64 2.12~rc1-2build2 [159 kB]
    Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libjpeg-turbo8 amd64 2.1.2-0ubuntu1 [134 kB]
    Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
```

Comment: and we do not support home and enduser questions. mostly solveable by apt update and a stable dns resolution

Comment: Could you explain how "apt update" resolved this 404 issue? Thanks.

Comment: After posting this question, I am not allowed to post any more questions. Any one know why? This question is not out of scope. This forum is for those who needs help, not for experts, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apt uses a local cache to speed up fetching new packages.
This package could get stale.

### Location of lists

```bash
/var/lib/apt/lists
```

### what update do

Manpage Says about it:

```
      update (apt-get(8))
           update is used to download package information from all configured sources. Other commands operate on this data to e.g. perform package
           upgrades or search in and display details about all packages available for installation.
```

Mostly, when using different sources or changed it, then is it recommended running a clean before

```
      clean
           clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from /var/cache/apt/archives/ and
           /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.
```

## Why did it solve now an 404 error?

We have to look into an `Packages`

to keep confusion low, i use one of the packges:

```bash
Package: libasound2-data
Source: alsa-lib
Version: 1.2.8-1
Installed-Size: 200
Maintainer: Debian ALSA Maintainers <pkg-alsa-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Replaces: libasound2 (<< 1.2.8-1)
Recommends: alsa-ucm-conf, alsa-topology-conf
Suggests: alsa-utils
Breaks: libasound2 (<< 1.2.8-1)
Description: Configuration files and profiles for ALSA drivers
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: https://www.alsa-project.org/
Description-md5: 41f916f1c1cbcf480b3b7fe38fbcef23
Tag: role::shared-lib
Section: libs
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2-data_1.2.8-1_all.deb
Size: 20488
MD5sum: 8cdd32445982638bf5d024453da19673
SHA256: fe0780d2d3674b2977e0acb0d48b448ad72ba1642564b7dc537f55e839984c2d
```

It tells apt, that the file is located in `pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2-data_1.2.8-1_all.deb`

But it could happen, that the file has been replaced by another version and may now unavailable. That is the reason, why it is so important to execute `apt update` regularly before installing packages.

Comment: Thanks. But the 404 error shows that IP address can not be found, not a file.

Comment: error 404 is file not found

Comment: After posting this question, I am not allowed to post any more questions. Any one know why? This question is not out of scope. This forum is for those who needs help, not for experts, right?

Comment: I am wondering who has the right to lock other accounts :)

Comment: The best way to address your request is by posting it on meta.serverfault.com. However, please note that if your question is about how to handle a 404 error on a home computer or end-user device, it may be off-topic. The focus of this platform is on managing information technology systems in a business environment and the question should have a direct impact on it. Also, keep in mind that you need to be a business administrator in charge of this environment.

Comment: And shortly responded to the question "this forum is for help not experts" I am sorry to inform you that this is wrong. Superuser.com is the best choice for you imho, moreover here some helpful links: [help] ontopic: [help/on-topic], don't ask:[help/dont-ask], behavior: [help/behavior] and meta help: [meta-help]